# How to implement higher ranking for search hits whose terms occur earlier in the text

Tags: elasticsearch, search, full-text-search, fuzzy-search

I'm trying to implement search-as-you-type movie title search. I wish my search to rank titles which start with entered prefix higher than those which has this prefix in a latter terms.

For example, for query "**termi**" I expect results in the following order:

1. **Termi**nal
2. **Termi**nator
3. Lady-**termi**nator
4. Quarantine 2: **Termi**nal

It is also essential to allow misprints in query terms that user has already fully typed (e.g in ***Pirats** of the Carib*... first term should be considered as "**pirates**")

I'm using the following mapping in my index:

```
{
        "mappings": {
            "dynamic": False,
            "properties": {      
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                },       
                "title_on_the_fly": {"type": "search_as_you_type"},
            },
        }
    }
```

And this query:

```
"query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    # --------- title -------------------
                    {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": query,                 
                            "type": "phrase_prefix",
                            "fields": [
                                "title_on_the_fly",
                                "title_on_the_fly._2gram",
                                "title_on_the_fly._3gram",
                            ],
                            "operator": "and",
                            "boost": 15,
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": query,
                            "type": "bool_prefix",
                            "fields": [
                                "title_on_the_fly",
                                "title_on_the_fly._2gram",
                                "title_on_the_fly._3gram",
                            ],
                            "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                            "operator": "and",
                            "boost": 8,
                        }
                    },
                    
                    # ---------- Fuzzy single word title ------
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "title": {
                                "query": query,
                                "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                                "operator": "and",
                                "boost": 6,
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    
                ],
                "minimum_should_match": 1,
            }
        },
```

My current query is doing well with misprints and prefix search, but ignores the position of hitting term, so, for example, I could sometimes get on **termi** query something like:

1. Lady-**termi**nator
2. **Termi**nator
3. ...

Is there any way to fix ranking? How should I change mappings/query to achieve this?

Comment: With the data you informed I tried to simulate and got the results you expected. Maybe it's because my data mass is small or the query informed is not the same as you run.

Comment: @rabbitbr are ```_score``` values for your results all the same?